# angular meteor How update user data in client/myComponent.js but not in the google console

Tags: meteor, terminal, console, angular-meteor, meteor-useraccounts

The aim is to transfert for exemple 2€ from user1 to user2

**model/myComponents.js**

```
Meteor.users.allow({
  update: function (userId) {   
    //check if an user is connected
    if(userId == null){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  },
  remove: function () {
    return false;
  }
});
```

**client/myComponents.js**

```
...
this.chooseWinner = (subject,comment) => {
...
// this works
Meteor.users.update({_id: comment.user_id}, {$set:{credit : winCash}});
...
```

**In the google chrome terminal, I can do this :**

```
Meteor.userId();

I obtain something like : "HTjgBTBcBk4npQSBe"
```

**After in the google chrome terminal, I ca do this :**

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: "HTjgBTBcBk4npQSBe"}, {$set:{credit : 12.34}});

!!!! Then the credit of this user is modified !!!!!
```

**How can I do to update in client/myComponent.js but not in the google console ???**

Thank you

Comment: Can you try to use Meteor.Call() with server side method to update?

Comment: @Leaf yes, it's easily the right way. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Leaf,

I didn't use anymore "allow" or "deny".

It's safer with meteor method

I used this doc : http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/meteor-methods

Hope, this can help someone.